# Open external links in inappbrowser plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some news pages that have the content fetched from various sources so the html may vary. All of this news contain links `<a href="...">Text</a>`.
What i want is to open all of this link in the inAppBrowser plugin. What i tried is the following:

```
document.onclick = function (e: Event) {

                e = e || window.event;
                let element: any = e.target || e.srcElement;
                if (element.tagName == 'A') {

                    InAppBrowser.open(element.href, "_blank", "location=yes");
                    return false;
                }
            };
```

So i am catching all clicks and if the element its "A" i open the inAppBrowser. This kinda works, but the thing is some of the links are like

```
<a href=".."><strong>Text</strong></a>
```

So in this case, the tagName is STRONG not A. Again, there is no special rule, it can be an image, a span, etc.

What is the recommended way for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to change the condition to

```
if(element.href!=undefind&&element.href!="")
```

So whatever the tag would be , if there is a link in href attribute it opens the inAppBrowser.

Comment: Its the same result, the click event doesn't propagate to the child, so i gonna still check element.href for a strong element.